# mySQL query - simple mathematical issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 telephone numbers for each person. Some of them only have telephone filled in others only have telephone2 filled in and some have both.

I am trying to find other people with the same telephone number, either telephone = telephone, telephone = telephone2, telephone2 = telephone, telephone2 = telephone2

Problem is that if telephone1 is null and then my existing code will match it to the next person with a telephone number regardless of match if it has telephone or telephone2 null. What do I need to add to the code.

```
    function getothers($tid,$criteria,$telephone,$telephone2,$elector){
                global $dbh;
                $tid = '-TID'.$tid;
                 $sql = "SELECT * FROM electors 
WHERE (telephone > 0 OR telephone2 > 0)
AND records NOT RLIKE '$tid'
AND (telephone IN ('$telephone','$telephone2') 
OR telephone2 IN ('$telephone','$telephone2')) 
AND ID != '$elector'  LIMIT 10";
                return $dbh->query($sql);
            }
```

Comment: tried using IS NOT NULL? or remove NULL from the field definition

Comment: telephone>0 implies your storing them as numbers. This is a bad idea. 003531111 is a telephone "number", 3531111 is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T_el.*
FROM (electors AS T_el) LEFT JOIN (electors AS T_dup)
ON (T_el.ID!=T_dup.ID
  AND (
    (T_el.telephone IS NOT NULL AND (T_el.telephone=T_dup.telephone OR T_el.telephone=T_dup.telephone2))
    OR
    (T_el.telephone2 IS NOT NULL AND (T_el.telephone2=T_dup.telephone OR T_el.telephone2=T_dup.telephone2))
    )
)
WHERE T_dup.ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T_el.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getothers($tid,$criteria,$telephone,$telephone2,$elector){
            global $dbh;
            $tid = '-TID'.$tid;
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM electors WHERE (telephone > 0 AND telephone IN ('$telephone','$telephone2'))  OR (telephone2 > 0 AND telephone2 IN ('$telephone','$telephone2')) $criteria AND records NOT RLIKE '$tid' AND ID != '$elector'  LIMIT 10";
            return $dbh->query($sql);
        }
```